# Asking a question about the items() method in Python

Tags: python

Here is a bit of code:

```
users = {
    'aeinstein': {
        'first': 'albert',
        'last': 'einstein',
        'location': 'princeton',
        },

'mcurie': {
    'first': 'marie',
    'last': 'curie',
    'location': 'paris',
    },

}

for username, user_info in users.items():
    print(f"\nUsername: {username}")
    full_name = f"{user_info['first']} {user_info['last']}"
    location = user_info['location']

print(f"\tFull name: {full_name.title()}")
print(f"\tLocation: {location.title()}")
```

When accessing different keys within a dictionary, there are some variables being declared. When declaring variables associated to dictionary keys and values, is it assumed the first variable declared is always the key? Notice the `username` variable, there is nothing identifying that from the dictionary to identify it as the key. As well with `user_info`, nothing identifying that as the value. For example, what if I declared the `user_info` first, then the `username`?

Comment: You mean if you did `for user_info, username in users.items()`? Then `user_info` would be the key (e.g. `'aeinstein'`) and `username` would be the value (i.e. a dictionary). `items()` doesn't care what variables you assign to, it returns an iterator of `(key, value)` pairs per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: Yes `items` returns tuples of `(key, value)` so when you unpack them the key will be first and the value will be second. Or more generally when you unpack a tuple the variables are unpacked based on the order in the tuple.

Comment: Don't count on the order of a dictionary, that is not what it is meant for. Use the `[]` to access the items you want e.g. `users['aeinstein']['first']`

Comment: Wow, that was a quick response.  You all are amazing people.  Thank you for helping me make sense of this.

Answer (score 0):

> **`items()`**
> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items (`(key, value)` pairs).
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

This is what guarantees the order of the items. It explicitly returns an iterable (a *view*, let's leave aside the details, it's something you can *iterate over*) of `(key, value)` pair tuples.

If you just did `for foo in users.items()`, then `foo` would be this tuple. You can unpack a tuple:

```
key, value = ('foo', 'bar')
```

And that's what you're doing in the loop too, unpacking the tuple:

```
for key, value in users.items():
```